# flutter multithreading with custom objects

Tags: flutter, multithreading, dart-isolates

I am developing large flutter project, in which I have large lists, maps(STMs) with custom objects on it and I'm facing **performance issues** especially when I try to find specific objects in these collections and manipulating them, issues like animations being not smooth/laggy cause of the high load on the main thread.
Unfortunately flutter does not support sharing objects between threads its literally (**Isolates**).
So, any solution to share custom objects between Isolates in flutter? serialization is not a choice for my case its not really practical to serialize/deserialize huge lists to apply trivial modifications on them.

So is there any solutions for this?

I have searched extensively for a convenient solution, but unfortunately, I have not found any practical options.